# Why Can't Muscles Push When They Return To Their Original Length?

Tags: physiology, muscles

I understand that muscles can only contract and shorten and thus can only pull, but why can't a muscle push when it relaxes and returns to its initial length?

Comment: Try to push something with a piece of string :-)  To push with something, it needs to be rigid.  Muscles aren't.

Answer (score -2):

In effect, the "Push" does happen automatically when the muscle relaxes.
The muscle itself does not push and cannot push, but it sets off the connected bones from the adjoining joint/s after its contraction.
It's the same as firing a gun or a catapult or a rubber band - create big tension in the contraction or pull, and let go suddenly, and there is the Push, achieved on relaxation.

Comment: You are now answering a lot of old (and sometimes downvoted) questions. There is nothing bad on this per se, but please do not use the answer box to simply write a small comment below the question. If you have to add something, please add it but write real answer which explain something and add references. Since you are a new user, I also recommend you take a look into the [help section](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help) on what is expected from answers here.This avoids deletion of your answers.